# psycopg2 connection already closed

Tags: python, postgresql

In one of our environments we execute quite heavy query from python script using psycopg2. It takes more then 10 min to execute but we get a result and can consume received data.

When we move the same script to different environment then after ~5min we get an error:
psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed

What may be the reason for that?

Comment: because the timeout in your other environment is set lower. You can raise the timeout setting (sorry i'm not familiar with postgres so you'll have to look it up) Or you could optimize your query.

Comment: The settings in the postgres are the same so thats not correct answer

Comment: did you find a satisfying answer/solution?